# Wordpress & Docker Compose - "Error establishing a database connection" / "Database Error" using wp-config.php

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on Debian based VM. I'v connected to it via SSH.

I'm doing a simple compose projcet, but my localhost throws *Error establishing a database connection*

My Dockerfile with wordpress image. I use COPY to pass configs from file to my container

```
FROM wordpress:latest

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data wp-config.php /var/www/html/
```

My wp-config.php

```
<?php

define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'wordpress' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'wordpress' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'my-awesome-database:3306' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );

$table_prefix = 'wp_';

define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

My docker-compose.yml"

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-awesome-database: # My database service
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: my-awesome-database
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress # Mandatory env
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
    networks: # Adding two containers to one bridge net to communicate each other
      - my-awesome-network 
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes: # To save database configs after restart container
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  my-awesome-wordpress:
    build: . # Build image from Dockerfile
    container_name: my-awesome-wordpress
    networks:
      - my-awesome-network
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes: # Saving wp-config.php file, if reboot container
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - my-awesome-database
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

networks:
  my-awesome-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  wordpress:
    driver: local
  mysql:
    driver: local
```

I did all like in official docker sample [here](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/official-documentation-samples/wordpress/) but it doesn't works

Wordpress [says](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/wordpress/common-errors/#Error_Establishing_Database_Connection) that this error could happened becouse of wrong DB vars.

So, I assume, something wrong with `wp-config.php` or with evironments in compose file, but don't understand what actually

Comment: The docker-compose.yaml you've shared is not properly indented. Also, can you share the full and exact error message you're facing?

Comment: my-awesome-database:3306  should be localhost:3306

Comment: @NicoHaase
You mean check the log file?
When I'm opening a localhost it throws Database Error. Expected is Wordpress start page with choosing language. 
(I will change indent)

Comment: @nbk
1) I'v tried this earlier and it doesn't help
2) My task says, that I have to use custom endpoint

Comment: "My task says, that I have to use custom endpoint" - what does that mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase
"Define your DB endpoint. Format is like here: db_endpoint:db_port; e.g. localhost:3306 -- a default value provided by Wordpress. Insert yours instead". What it said in my task. But, if it will work with localhost at least, it will be solution too

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase
Done. Please, response if it still not enough clear

Comment: @nbk it most definitely should *not* be localhost when trying to connect between two containers created by docker-compose. Localhost points to the WP container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel myself really dumb. The solution was just clear volumes using

```
docker volume prune # Make sure you don't have important data in volumes!
```

Nothing to change in code just recreate volumes

**Why is this issue possible?**

I guess, becouse of changing `docker-compose.yml` and `wg-config.php`.

After changes docker used OLD data and that's why I couldn't connect to my database.

Thanks all, who spend their time!